# Inspect (rpm -qp) multiple RPM files, each bundled in different TAR files

Tags: tar, rpm, sles

I was wondering the possible best time case solutions to extract each RPM files from a list of TAR bundle and get the package information from those files.

So, I have a list of tar bundles in a directory, containing at least one RPM. For these, I have tried the simplest solution to loop over, extract and then peak into each RPM package using a bash script, which is taking a significant amount of time given the TAR bundles are over 20+.

I also tried bulk extraction using `cat *.tar | tar -xvf - -i`, then  `rpm -qp #list of files` to get the package names which gave me an improvement over my last approach.

I know that I could peek into TAR bundle and get the .rpm file name, but since the name of the file containing a package has nothing to do with the name of the package, I need to check the RPM package as well.

The closest solution I could attempt was:

```
# given tarball-containing-wget-rpm-package.tar.gz contains wget.rpm 

bash$ time (cat tarball-containing-wget-rpm-package.tar.gz|gunzip|tar --wildcards --extract '*.rpm' --to-stdout|rpm -qp /dev/stdin)
wget-1.11.4-1.40.1

real    0m0.049s
user    0m0.044s
sys     0m0.004s
```

which is pretty quick, but doesn't give right info if a TAR bundle contains more than one RPM files.

So, what I’m asking is:

- Can I bulk extract all TAR file to stdout and peek in the RPM files then?
- Can I perform this operation without extracting the files from TAR bundle?
- How can I modify the above command to work with a single TAR bundle containing multiple RPM?

Comment: The manpage states that the `-p` option expects a single package file, so I don't think you'll be able to use this approach. As a side note, you can replace `cat filename|gunzip|tar` with `tar -z -f filename` if you have GNU tar.

Comment: @Haxiel `rpm -qp --queryformat '%{NAME}\t%{VERSION}\t%{RELEASE}\n' a1.rpm a2.rpm a3.rpm` is working by giving package information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the `rpm` command can correctly process one file from `stdin` and fails when there are mutiple files involved, the following approach is a potential solution.

With GNU `tar`, you can use the `--to-command` option to send each file's content to the `rpm` command.

```
tar -zf tarball.gz --wildcards --extract '*.rpm' --to-command='rpm -qp /dev/stdin'
```

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Writing-to-an-External-Program.html#SEC87):

> ```
> --to-command=command
> ```
>
> Extract files and pipe their contents to the standard input of *command*. When this option is used, instead of creating the files
>   specified, tar invokes *command* and pipes the contents of the files to
>   its standard output. The *command* may contain command line arguments
>   (see Running External Commands, for more detail).
>
> Notice, that *command* is executed once for each regular file extracted. Non-regular files (directories, etc.) are ignored when this
>   option is used.

Comment: @TanmayBaranwal if you have a new question, please post it separately. You can link back to this one if it adds helpful context.